# Progressbar and TextView updates in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-progressbar

I create a "small" example for my question. I have two classes: *MainActivity* and *Berechnung*. The Class Berechnung calculates some things that should cost a little bit of time, only for testing the progressbar. 
First, the MainActivity:

```
package com.example.matthias.progressbar;


import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Runnable{


    Button btn;
    ProgressBar progress;
    TextView tv;

    Berechnung langeBerechnung;
    ArrayList<Integer> erg;
    boolean laeuftNoch;
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }



    @Override
    public void run() {
        int progressWert = 0;
        tv.setText("Berechnung gestartet.");
        while(laeuftNoch){
            progressWert = progressWert + 5;

            if(progressWert < 100){
                progress.setProgress(progressWert);
            }else {
                progressWert = 0;
                progress.setProgress(progressWert);
            }
        }
        tv.setText("Berechnung beendet.");
        progress.setProgress(100);
    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        handler.post(this);

        Callable<ArrayList<Integer>> call = new Berechnung();
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Future<ArrayList<Integer>> future = executor.submit(call);

        try {
            ArrayList<Integer> erg = future.get();
            int index = ((Berechnung)call).getIndex();
            int grenze = ((Berechnung)call).getGrenze();
            Log.d("App", "Die längste Folge bis " + grenze + " entsteht für die Eingabe " + index + " und hat eine Länge von " + erg.size() + ".");
            ((Berechnung)call).ausgabe(erg);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Nothing
        }
        laeuftNoch = false;
    }


}
```

Now the second Class:

```
package com.example.matthias.progressbar;

import android.provider.Settings;
import android.telecom.Call;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class Berechnung implements Callable<ArrayList<Integer>> {

    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> all = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    int index;
    int grenze;

    public ArrayList<Integer> call(){
        all = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        all.add(0, new ArrayList<Integer>());

        grenze = 35000;

        for(int i=1; i <= grenze; i++){
            Log.d("App", "Berechne collatz(" + i + ")");

            list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            all.add(i, collatz(i));
        }

        int max = all.get(1).size();
        index = 1;
        for(int i=2; i <= grenze; i++){
            if(all.get(i).size() > max){
                max = all.get(i).size();
                index = i;
            }
        }


        return all.get(index);
    }


    public ArrayList<Integer> collatz(int n){
        list.add(n);
        if(n > 1) {
            if (n % 2 == 0) {
                n = n/2;
                return collatz(n);
            } else {
                n = 3*n + 1;
                return collatz(n);
            }
        }else{
            return list;
        }
    }

    public int getIndex(){
        return index;
    }

    public int getGrenze(){
        return grenze;
    }

    public void ausgabe(ArrayList<Integer> l){
        for(int i=0; i < l.size(); i++){
            Log.d("App", (i+1) + ".)\t" + l.get(i) + "");
        }
    }

}
```

My problem lies probably in the MainActivity. Neither the TextView (tv) nor the ProgressBar (progress) will be updated. In a first step I used a normal Thread which changes the textview and the progressbar, but I get a *call from wrong thread exception*. Then I read on some webpages, that I need a Handler for this problem. But I do not understand how I have to use this.

Maybe the xml-file helps for this problem:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.matthias.progressbar.MainActivity">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="65dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="180dp"
        android:text="Starte Berechnung"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="onClick" />

    <TextView
        android:text='Drücken Sie den Button "Starte Berechnung".'
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am not certain which class makes the problem, therefor I gave you all files. The Berechnung-class use also an console output, which blocked the Thread. Maybe this is also a problem (?)

Please, can anybody help me to understand my progrmming mistakes?

Best regards, Matthias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a completely different approach for this.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
}
```

In this `onCreate` method I would put the `onClick` listener for the button.
(`btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener)`)
In this method you can write your "run" stuff.

If this doesn't really answer your question, I might have misunderstood you.
So what do these things do?

```
@Override
public void run() {
    int progressWert = 0;
    tv.setText("Berechnung gestartet.");
    while(laeuftNoch){
        progressWert = progressWert + 5;

        if(progressWert < 100){
            progress.setProgress(progressWert);
        }else {
            progressWert = 0;
            progress.setProgress(progressWert);
        }
    }
    tv.setText("Berechnung beendet.");
    progress.setProgress(100);
}

public void onClick(View v){
    handler.post(this);

    Callable<ArrayList<Integer>> call = new Berechnung();
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Future<ArrayList<Integer>> future = executor.submit(call);

    try {
        ArrayList<Integer> erg = future.get();
        int index = ((Berechnung)call).getIndex();
        int grenze = ((Berechnung)call).getGrenze();
        Log.d("App", "Die längste Folge bis " + grenze + " entsteht für die Eingabe " + index + " und hat eine Länge von " + erg.size() + ".");
        ((Berechnung)call).ausgabe(erg);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Nothing
    }
    laeuftNoch = false;
}
```

You did not talk about them in anyway and for which part do we need your "Berechnung" Class? Also what is the **exact problem** you have?

#### EDIT:

So maybe it seems like it does not update to you because you have no `sleep` in your thread.

```
while(laeuftNoch) {
    progressWert = progressWert + 5;

    if(progressWert < 100){
        progress.setProgress(progressWert);
    } else {
        progressWert = 0;
        progress.setProgress(progressWert);
    }
}
```

This `while-loop` takes NO time! It doesn't really pause or do I miss something? It runs straight through in like 1 ms. So you should add something like `Thread.sleep(milliseconds)`.
And also what is the purpose of assigning the list every time in the `for loop`?

```
for(int i=1; i <= grenze; i++){
    Log.d("App", "Berechne collatz(" + i + ")");

    list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    all.add(i, collatz(i));
}
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer. Sry. maybe it is useful to have the xml file. I will change this immediately.

In the XML file I say, the method _onClick()_ will be called, if the button will be clicked, therefore I wroted this in this way.
My idea for the run method is, the progressbar has the maximum by 100 and in +5 steps the progressbar should be increased and if the progressValue is 100, then it should start from 0. This should repeated until the calculation call() in Berechnung is terminated. Then also the TextView should updated to "Berechnung beendet".

Comment: I added two more improvement suggestions to my answer (at the bottom). But I still did not get your goal/problem completely.

Comment: You're right, the sleep-statement was missing. I add this in my code, but I have still the same problem. This is:

1.) If I click the button, the TextView should directly change to _Berechnung gestartet_
2.) If I click the button, the Progressbar should increase to 100, then jump to 0 and increase again, and so on.

But instead, the TextView Text holds the stadard text _Drücken Sie den Button "Starte Berechnung"._ (as you can see in the xml file). You now what I mean?